# Laravel based app - Adding a page but how?

Tags: php, routes

I downloaded an app that uses the Laravel framework. I never heard of his framework before and therefore have my problems adding a new page. 
I googled the whole day but cannot figure out how to add a simple page. I am therefore sorry asking this simple to answer question but I just need to add one page...nothing more.

Can anyone help me here? I figured out that the app works with routings.

There are subfolders in the folder /views called "item", "contact", "error" and so on.

In "item" I have php files like "add.php", "edit.php" and so on.

I need a page called "editplus.php" where I just copy the contents of "edit.php" with some changed content. That's it

I added a link in the menu but when I click "editplus" I will get a 404 error.

So there must be a file where I add the infomation, that "editplus" must show to my file "editplus.php"

I really looked in almost every file but cannot see where i would do that.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by adding a route to app/route.php file
1. you can simply return your content like this and it will be displayed on page

```
Route::get('foo/bar', function()
{
   return 'Hello World';
});
```

2. you can do it using a controller

`Route::get('user', array('uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));`

more details of controllers here http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers

Laravel is simplest framework of all.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out